# Using aggregate functions (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database

I heard couple of times that when we use aggregate functions it is good practice (almost must have) to use HAVING or GROUP BY in some query. Can someone explain this a bit more?
As far as I get it, this would help us summ or results, but is there any big difference in performance there? Do we MUST have HAVING or GROUP BY in queries where we are searching for row with MAX function for some column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that in such situation it could be very usefull to read documentation

> - If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.

As you see if you don't use `GROUP BY` will means to not use any aggregate function. So it's actually a must to do and not qn option.

Learn more [**here**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: Well, that sounds ok. But in case where I have to find row with MAX column value in all data from the table, should I use MAX there or ORDER by COLUMN_NAME DESC? Which one is actually faster and more correct?

Comment: Max will only select max value according with group by while order by will order all results by the column you are using, this actually not the same thing. By the way if my answer was correct and fulffilled your answer you might consider to accept it, so you will also help people in yhe future with similar problems.

Comment: I think you are not getting me... I know it isn't a same thing when you look that way. But let's take a look on another example.
-- Mike, 200$, Register user
Annie, 400$, Unregister user
Tony, 300$, Admin --

In this example, I can use MAX for getting max value for $ and order by DESC on $. This would gave basicly same result except in order by I am getting all rows, and MAX would return only one. Which one is actually a faster and better to use in this example?

Comment: Alright, so post another question so I might help you out

Comment: Sry, pressed enter by mistake. I updated my question :)

Comment: Better to put a new question with this scenario, so you might be helped by more people than only me

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49302/discussion-between-fabio-and-petart)

Comment: Man i'm writing you in the chat

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a table

```
'name' | 'sex'
'jeff' | 'M'
'jen'  | 'F'
'mike' | 'M'

SELECT sex, count(*) FROM myTable GROUP BY sex
```

This would return

```
'M', 2
'F', 1
```

Basically, you need the GROUP BY statement because you need to tell the database how to aggregate the result set (i.e. collect similar rows).

Comment: This wasn't actually my question... It is ok to use group by here in combination with count if you want to count some rows specially. I came up on this question when I wanted to get row with maximum price and then I used MAX function. However, I found out later that using MAX in this cases is not best solution. I red somewhere that ORDER DESC would be better solution. Is ORDER DESC actually faster then MAX?